# Postgres - convert dateString to int8

Tags: postgresql, datetime, type-conversion, epoch

How can i convert this string to a int8 in PostgreSQL 12?

`2021-10-18T17:45:22Z`

i tried:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-10-18T17:45:22Z'::text,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ')::int8
to_char('2021-10-18T17:45:22Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ')::integer
```

and a few variations of these but without any success.

The Input string cannot change because it is passed this way by an external software.

Comment: What's that integer supposed to mean? Dates in all databases except SQLite are separate binary types, not strings. Almost all languages have date types too, so there's little reason to convert a date to something else

Comment: As for `2021-10-18T17:45:22Z` that's not just a date, it's a date with an offset. This represents different times in each timezone. Removing the offset loses important information

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The Z at the end stands for Zulu time zone, i.e. UTC. So it can be safely omitted given that timestamps are stored in UTC by default

Comment: @Patrick I know what this means and how those defaults aren't really. Check [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't tell us what the integer value is supposed to represent.  One general approach here would be to work with UNIX timestamps.  For example:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM '2021-10-18 17:45:22'::timestamp);  -- 1634579122
```

The value `1634579122` is the number of seconds which has elapsed since January 1, 1970.

Comment: You are right, i fogot to mention that. unix timestamp is exactly what I need. thank you

Comment: @sharkyenergy why do you need it? Dates are built-in types in almost all databases and languages. Using the correct type is actually a lot safer and more portable than something ambiguous like a Unix timestamp (what timezone? what precision?)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the database i got (not managed by me) has the date saved as int8...